# Android Things Pin naming convention

Tags: android, android-things

Why different boards have different GPIO names in Android Things?

For example, in Raspberry PI 3, there are `BCM6`, while Intel Edison with the Arduino breakout has `IO12`, `IO13`, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GPIO (and other peripheral port handle) are named after the SOC/SOM documentation for each supported board.

Boards like the Edison Arduino breakout or the Sparkfun Edison Pi block have the same pin name directly on their silk screen.

When this information is missing, you can consult the pinout reference in the reference documentation:

- [Intel Edison Arduino](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/edison-arduino-io.html)
- [Intel Edison Sparkfun Pi block](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/edison-sparkfun-io.html)
- [Pico i.MX6UL](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/pico-io.html)
- [Raspberry Pi 3](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi-io.html)

Or popular online references like https://pinout.xyz